# Arduino pro micro crashing

Tags: arduino-pro-micro

My arduino pro micro started behaving weird. I noticed it had crashed with very simple code on it (basically just two lines of fastled code followed by a delay. Then it didn't appear as a USB device on my macbook anymore. I reset it (pulling the rst pin to gnd) and that then allowed me to upload smaller sketches but not bigger ones. The smaller sketch only works for a short period of time. then the arduino just stalls. (Serial output also stops). Any idea what i can do? Or do i just have to toss the board and get myself a new one?

Comment: Could you explain what happens if you try to upload bigger sketches? PS.
please note that the fastLED library is a few hundred lines of code. So that fact that **your** code is only two lines doesn't actually mean your program is simple or small.

Comment: the board doesn't appear via usb anymore. two LEDs on the board light up during the upload process and the board is lost `Couldn't find a Board on the selected port. Check that you have the correct port selected.  If it is correct, try pressing the board's reset button after initiating the upload.
Board at /dev/cu.usbmodem14101 is not available` - Started to happen with smaller sketches too, so i just assume the board is fried.

Comment: You could try reflashing the bootloader, but I'm doubtful that would help. Have your tried a different USB port?